# iOS: how to detect whether rectangular area is at all obscured e.g. by keyboard?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I know how to move a rectangular area out from under the keyboard, by scrolling it to any area above the keyboard, but how can I detect whether it is obscured in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

Just use the `NSNotificationCenter` to register for `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` and `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` notifications; move your views then. The notification's userInfo dictionary will have a key `UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey` which you can use to animate the movement of your views with the keyboard.